# SqlCommand not working on dbtype int foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an issue here, previously i was getting values from `SqlCommand` from a `varchar` column in my table.

With this code :

```
connection.Open();

request += "SELECT * ";
//SqlCommand GetCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT  RA_BINAIRE FROM MR_RAPPORT WHERE RA_ID=@RA_ID");
request += "FROM " + table + " WHERE " + searchcol + " = " + "@ID";
//request += "FROM " + table + " WHERE CO_ID = " + "@ID";

SqlCommand GetCommand = new SqlCommand(request, connection);
Int16 convertedValue = this.ConvertByType(searchcolType, code);
Console.WriteLine(convertedValue.GetType());

var convertedValueHelper = SqlHelper.GetDbType(convertedValue.GetType());
SqlDbType dbType = SqlHelper.GetSqlByType(searchcolType);
//var param = new SqlParameter()
//{
//    SqlDbType = SqlHelper.GetSqlByType(searchcolType),
//    TypeName = SqlHelper.GetDbType(convertedValue.GetType()),
//    Value = Convert.ToInt16("12")
//};
//var param = new SqlParameter("ID", convertedValue);
//GetCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
GetCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", convertedValue);
GetCommand.Connection = connection;

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(GetCommand);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

SqlDataReader reader = GetCommand.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(reader);

string jsonStr = Utils.DataTableToJsonObj(dataTable);
connection.Close();
```

It works fine with my column `varchar` with type string, but with my foreign key id which is `SqlDbType.SmallInt` and value is int16, it's not retrieving data.

I tried with another `varchar` column, and it's also working.

Can't find out why ....

Any help here would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance guys,

Answer (score 0):

Re guys,
I solved it using sqldataadapter instead of reader ...
Don't know why ...
But this is working

```
                    request += "SELECT * ";
                //SqlCommand GetCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT  RA_BINAIRE FROM MR_RAPPORT WHERE RA_ID=@RA_ID");
                request += "FROM " + table + " WHERE " + searchcol + " = " + "@ID";
                //request += "FROM " + table + " WHERE CO_ID =12";
                SqlCommand GetCommand = new SqlCommand(request, connection);
                var convertedValue = this.ConvertByType(searchcolType, code);
                SqlDbType convertedValueHelper = SqlHelper.GetDbType(convertedValue.GetType());
                GetCommand.Parameters.Add("ID", convertedValueHelper).Value = convertedValue;
                GetCommand.Connection = connection;
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(GetCommand);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                string jsonStr = Utils.DataTableToJsonObj(dt);
                connection.Close();
                return Ok(jsonStr);
```

Have a nice week end =)